# Pipe stdout while script has read command

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a small script (called stc) to create a SecureToken with `stoken`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read Password
read -p "Password " -s PASS

TOKEN=$(stoken --stdin <<< "$PASS")
xclip -sel c <<< "$TOKEN"

if [[ ! -t 1 ]]; then
  echo $TOKEN
fi
```

In normal circumstances it copies the token to the clipboard. When there is a pipe the token should be written to `stdout` (this is working) but for some reason the next command in the pipe is not executed. I think this has to do with the `read` but have no idea how to solve this.

For example

```
$ stc | tee
```

results in

```
$ stc | tee
Password <token echo>
<hangs forever>
```

Comment: Add some echo statements after every command so you can see exactly where it is hanging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xclip` forks a child process that runs in background to handle CLIPBOARD selection requests. Here, that child process will inherit the pipe and hold it open until it exits when some other process reclaims CLIPBOARD the selection. Here, just do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
# Read Password
IFS= read -rsp "Password: " PASS

TOKEN=$(printf %s "$PASS" | stoken --stdin)
printf %s "$TOKEN" | xclip -sel c > /dev/null

[ -t 1 ] || printf '%s\n' "$TOKEN"
```

(you also forgot the [`IFS=`, `-r` option to `read`](/q/209123), and the [quotes around `$TOKEN`](/q/171346) and that [`echo` can't be used for arbitrary data](/q/65803)).

Comment: Ah cool thank you! The token will be numbers only so echo should be okay but the IFS stuff I have not understood. Is this related to a password with spaces?

Comment: @Pascal, I've added links to relevant Q&As. You almost never want to use `read` without setting IFS for it and without `-r`. If `$TOKEN` is numeric only and `$IFS` is guaranteed to contain its default value, `echo $TOKEN`, though still nonsensical as there's no reason you would want to invoke split+glob, would be fine, but there's also no reason not to write the correct `printf '%s\n' "$TOKEN"`.

Comment: Many thanks!! All clear to me now ;-)